# How can I keep a user logged in with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, redux, store

I'm working on an app that has user authentication. Right now my log in is currently happening in a withAuth HOC, while my Nav component is set up to get the current user.

However, while the use can log in and access their profile page, once they leave profile, current user is empty.

How do I set up my store and/or components so that current user is available on every page.

I tried to pass user to my Nav component, but once you leave profile, there's no user at all

This is my withAuth HOC:

```
export default function withAuth(WrappedComponent) {

  class Something extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() { 

  **//checks if user is logged in before loading to the WrappedComponent (which in this case is the profile page)**

      if (!localStorage.token) {
        this.props.history.push("/login")
      }
      try {
        this.props.getCurrentUser()
        .catch(error => {
          this.props.history.push("/login")
        })
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.message === "Please log in") {
          this.props.history.push("/login")
        }
      }
      }

      render() {

        return (

<WrappedComponent />

      )}
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = {
      getCurrentUser: getCurrentUserAction

**//does a fetch to 'http://localhost:3000/profile' with the bearer token and returns the username**

    }

    return withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Something))
}
```

This is my Nav component (which is imported to every page):

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCurrentUser();

**//This should fetch from 'http://localhost:3000/profile' with the bearer token and return the username**

  }
...
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    user: state.user
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getCurrentUser: getCurrentUserAction,
  logout: userLogoutAction
};
```

I understand why user is visible in profile, but don't understand why it's not visible anywhere else

Comment: I have so many questions to this code. Could you comment what each of the piece of code does. Otherwise I think no one would be able to help you. For example:

// getCurrentUserAction is a function that does ...
setCurrentUser: getCurrentUserAction,

Comment: yeah, I'll do that now

Comment: I also removed the parts of the code that were redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When HoC component mounts it always mounts the Nav component as well.

Nav component has `this.props.getCurrentUser();` which is same thing as `this.props.setCurrentUser()`.

I bet you have some race condition that redirects the user back to login.

I'd suggest you to refactor your code and use redux properly, which in this scenario *could be*:

`getCurrentUserAction` handles the request to get user data if user is logged in, then dispatches `RECEIVE_USER` action, which changes the redux state (by reducer).

HoC makes sure user is logged in and dispatches the action when necessary.

Nav component uses **only** selector to get the user data it needs (since HoC acts here as a guard).

Above might not be the most optimal solution for you, but it could fix your problem.

Comment: This wasn't quite the answer, but in the process of refactoring my code, I realized there was a problem with how I was importing my actions the adapter file. Thanks for the advice